# Manage Caching for certain elements in TYPO3?

Tags: caching, typo3, typoscript, typo3-6.2.x

I have some complex menus that take (nearly) literally forever to render.

I use `nc_staticfilecache`, but for editors and logged in users, it would be great to be able to NOT re-render these menus at every page load.

I was already thinking about rendering the menu on a special doktype, fetching the rendered menu with a cron job, and storing it into the database or a file, which could then be used in the template.

On the other hand, is there an existing method for that case?

Answer (score 1):

The caching framework can handle this. There is a property `stdWrap.cache` which does exactly this Typoscript-Caching. Awesome!

Here's an article in german that departs exactly from my use case (megamenus)
http://www.typo3.net/beitraege/typo3-cache-befehl/

I've copied the poster's code here, simplified it a little and translated the comments:

```
/**
 * @author Oliver Thiele
 */

lib.megaNavigation = COA
lib.megaNavigation {
    wrap = <ul class="nav navbar-nav">|</ul>

    /**
     * Doesn't need to be cached, not slow
     */
    10 = TEXT
    10.value (
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Links</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="http://extern.example.com">Externer Link</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    )

    /**
     * Shouldn't be cached, highlighting is needed
     */
    20 = HMENU
    20 {
        // ... Normale Menügenerierung
        special = directory
        special.value = 1

        1 = TMENU
        1 {
            NO.wrapItemAndSub = <li>|<li>
            # …
        }
    }

    /**
     * That's the slow part we want to be cached
     */
    30 = COA
    30 {
        stdWrap {
            cache {
                /**
                 * Use language as key to identify different localisations
                 */
                key = meganavigation_contact_{TSFE:sys_language_uid}
                key.insertData = 1

                // tag can be used for later clearing
                tags = main_navigation, tx_slowextension

                /**
                 * must be seen in context of page caching
                 */
                lifetime = 3600
            }
        }


        # This would be the menu - could also be nested hmenus with content etc!
        20 < plugin.tx_slowextension_pi1

        /**
         * For testing: Timestamp
         */
        30 = TEXT
        30 {
            data = date: d.m.y H:i:s
            wrap = <li>|</li>
        }

    }
}
```

The docs are on http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Functions/Cache/Index.html